# UITabBarController check if tab selected for the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

This might sound easy. I want to check if tab was selected for the first time. And this goes for all the tabs. `NSUserDefaults` or any solution should work.

Comment: what does for the first time mean? Does it means in this time the app run, or the first time since the app is installed?

Comment: In this time. i.e. if app is removed from background, even then.

Comment: Its better if you restore state of application using UIViewControllerRestoration. Your all problems gone away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UITabBarDelegate, you could do this:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(YES) forKey:item.title];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

then later, when you want to see if it was selected, simply look at the user defaults using a function something like this:

```
 - (BOOL)didSelectItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title {

    NSNumber *value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:title];
    return value != nil;
}
```

You could observe UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and then clear all the user defaults, if you want to reset it at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should catch `UITabBarControllerDelegate` like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)selectingViewController {
    if (![selectingViewController isViewLoaded]) {
        //this is the first time we meet
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Good luck!

p/s: make sure that there is no calling to `[UIViewController view]` for `selectingViewController` before (example: call to preload `UIWebView` :D )

Answer (score 0):

Create a UITabBarItem category with a method called isFirstRun using **NSUserDefaults** with **tag** combination

Don't forget to set the tag for each UITabBarItem you want to track;
e.g:

```
UITabBarItem *bar1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *bar2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *bar3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
bar1.tag = 1001;
bar2.tag = 1002;
bar2.tag = 1003;

if([bar1 isFirstRun]) {
   //to something
   [bar1 setDidRun:YES];
}
```

***UITabBarItem+FirstRun.h***

```
#import "UITabBarItem.h"
@interface UITabBarItem (FirstRun)
- (BOOL) isFirstRun;
- (void) setDidRun:(BOOL) flag;
@end
```

***UITabBarItem+FirstRun.m***

```
#import "UITabBarItem+FirstRun.h"

@implementation UITabBarItem (FirstRun)

- (BOOL) isFirstRun {
   return return ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tab%ldDidRun", self.tag]];
}

- (void) setDidRun:(BOOL) flag {
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:flag forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tab%ldDidRun", bar.tag]];
}
```